# Friends in a queue

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a queue of **N** humans. At this queue there are two friends. What is the probability that between friends will be **M** humans. (M + 2 < N)

So, what we got:

- total number of combinations  = N!;

Lets take some example:

N=10, M=3. For that case, between friends can be 3 humans, any humans, so its not just 3!, its something like (10-2)! but grouped by 3... and in that place I stuck.

Can someone help with direction to solving?

Comment: Maybe use a different sample space. There are $\binom{N}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose an unordered pair of positions, There are $N-M-1$ ways to choose an unordered pair separated by $M$.

Comment: Impossible to answer without a hint of the underlying probability distribution. What kind of event are they queueing to? A concert? Then there should be a larger probability that people are queuing in small groups than individually. A cinema? Then higher probability in pairs, et.c..

Answer (score 3):

Say our two friends are $a$ and $b$. Then we can line the remaining people up in $(N-2)!$ ways. Then we can squeeze our two friends in such that there are $M$ people between them in $N-1-M$ ways, but we also have to choose which friend is first in line, so we get that there are a total of $2\cdot(N-2)!\cdot(N-1-M)$ arrangements such that $a$ and $b$ have $M$ people between them. I am assuming with this you can find the probability.

Comment: I believe there is a fencepost error in your computation. Between $(N-2)$ people, there will be $(N-1)$ gaps (incl. ends), thus $(N-1-M)$ sets of places for the duo to be squeezed in.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe a little simpler to use a sample space different from yours. There are $\binom{N}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose an unordered pair of two locations to be occupied by the two friends.

Now we count the *favourables*, the number if ways to choose an unordered pair of locations that are separated by $M$. Altogether, these $2$ locations  plus the block of $M$ take up $M+2$ spaces, leaving $N-M-2$. Thus we can have any of $0$ to $N-M-2$ people in front of the leftmost friend, a total  of $N-M-1$ choices.

The required probability is therefore $\frac{N-M-1}{\binom{N}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since only probability is asked for, we can just focus on ways of placing the "special" people ($A$ and $B$, say, with $m$ others in between)

For favorable placements, the $1st$ of them  can be in any position from $1$ to $(n-m-1)$,

so $A$ and $B$ can be placed in $2(n-m-1)$ ways against a total of $n(n-1)$ ways,

hence $Pr = \dfrac{2(n-m-1)}{n(n-1)}$

Comment: This assumes equiprobability of each configuration which is kind of unlikely no matter almost what they are queueing for.

Comment: Well, assuming they arrive randomly, it is equiprobable. Are you implying that ignoring people other than $A$ and $B$ is incorrect ?

Comment: In many real life queueing situations that is unlikely. Say for instance a rock concert or a bar it is likely people arrive to queue in small groups of variable sizes.

Comment: As I see it, in the absence of any hint to the contrary, this is a question about a single queue, with each configuration equiprobable. Of course, in real life, queues can be of multifarious types.